# Adding 2 vectors component with component using stack

Tags: c++, c++11, stack, queue

I have a problem with my C++ code. I need to make the sum of the vectors component by component. For example, if I have A(2,1) and B(3,3) the result should be (5,4). I tried to do something but apparently I have a problem and I don't know what to do. The error is: ,,No member called push in std::_1vector" My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack_base.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class App {
    public:
        Stack<T>  * stack;
        App(Stack<T> &stack) {
    this->stack = &stack;
}
      T sum(){
    Stack<T> *tempStack = stack;
    T sum=0;
    int size = stack->getTopLevel();
    for(int i=0; i<=size; i++) {
        sum+=tempStack->peek();
        tempStack->pop();
        }
    return sum;
}
      T substract(){
          Stack<T> tempStack = *stack;
          T substr=0;
          for(int i=0; i<=stack->getTopLevel(); i++) {
              substr-=tempStack.peek();
              tempStack.pop();
          }
          return substr;
      }
};
void display(vector<int> &v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    Stack<int> myStack;
    App<int> a(myStack);
    unsigned int i = 0;
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;

    // Populate v1 and v2 here

    // Check that v1 and v2 have the same length
    if (v1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        // error here
    }

    std::vector<int> v3; // This will hold the resulting vector
    // Preallocate the necessary memory if you like here, but it
    // isn't necessary and doesn't gain you much.
    for (auto i = 0ul; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        v3.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);
    }
    int x;
        cout << "Enter five integer values for v1" << endl;
        for(int i; i<5; i++)
        {
            cin >> x;
            v1.push_back(x);
        }
            cout << "Enter five integer values for v2" << endl;
            for(int i; i<5; i++)
            {
                cin >> x;
                v2.push_back(x);
            }
    cout << "Size of Vector= " << v2.size() << endl;
    display(v3);
        return 0;
    }
```

This is Stack:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NMAX 30 // pre-processing directive

template<typename T>
class Stack {
    private:
        // an array of NMAX dimension
        T stackArray[NMAX];
        /* the top of the stack, representing the INDEX of last element of the
        stackArray:0, 1, 2,....*/
        int topLevel;
    public:
        void push(T x) {
            //puts an element in the stack array

            //check if the stack array has the maximum dimension
            if (topLevel >= NMAX - 1)
            {
                cout<<"The stack is full: we have already NMAX elements!\n";
                //exit the function without making anything
                return;
            }
            /*add an element=> the index of the last element of the stack Array
            increases and put the value of the new element in the stack array*/
            stackArray[++topLevel] = x;
        }

        int isEmpty() {
            //returns 1, if topLevel>=0, meaning the stack array has elements
            // returns 0, otherwise
            return (topLevel < 0);
        }

        T pop() {
            // extracts and element from the stack array and returns the new top
            if (isEmpty()) {
                // the extraction is made only if the array is not empty
                cout<<"The stack is empty! \n";
                T x;
                return x;
            }
            // the topLevel decreases and the new top is changed
            return stackArray[--topLevel];
        }

        T peek() {
            // returns the top of the stack
           if (isEmpty()) {
                    // the extraction is made only if the array is not empty
                    cout<<"The stack is empty! \n";
                    T x;
                    return x;
            }
            return stackArray[topLevel];
        }
        void display(){
  for(int i=0;i<=topLevel;i++)
  cout<<stackArray[i];
  }
  bool search(T num){
  for(int i=0; i<=topLevel;i++)
    if(num==stackArray[i])
    return true;
   return false;
  }
  int getTopLevel(){
      return topLevel;
    }
        Stack() { // constructor
            topLevel = -1; // the stack is empty in the beginning
        }

    void sort(T s){
      if (!isEmpty()) {
        T x = Pop(s);
        sort(s);
        push(s, x);
    }
  }

        ~Stack() { // destructor
        }
};
```

Comment: Your vectors are empty. And what is `Stack`?

Comment: I edited it, it's a class where I store the elements, I add to the stack, I delete it and so on

Comment: I tried to add something with v1.insert(1,2,4) but it doesn't work, am I using it incorrect? Thanks! Or also with v1.push

Answer (score 0):

You are never adding any elements to your vector. In the preceding three lines, you attempt to access elements that do not exist, but the vectors only do bounds checking if you call the 'at' method instead of using the bracket notation. What are you trying to accomplish in that for-loop?

To add two vectors of the same length pair-wise, which is what I think you want, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;

// Populate v1 and v2 here

// Check that v1 and v2 have the same length
if (v1.size() != v2.size())
{
    // error here
}

std::vector<int> v3; // This will hold the resulting vector
// Preallocate the necessary memory if you like here, but it
// isn't necessary and doesn't gain you much.
for (auto i = 0ul; i < v1.size(); ++i)
{
    v3.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);
    // Debugging statement
    std::cout << "Added " << v1[i] << " and " << v2[i] << " to get " << v3[i] << " for index " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So how can I add elements to the vector?

Comment: now I get invalid operands  to binary expression if I try to display the sum of the components of the v1 and v2

Comment: cout<<"Sum of the elements are: "<<v3.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);

Comment: The push_back function does not return a value, so you cannot print it out. Documentation is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)